# Is it valid to have two input elements with the same name?

Tags: html, validation, forms

i.e.:

```
<form 1>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">
</form 1>
```

and

```
<form 2>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">
</form 2>
```

Is this allowed and valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form with multiple hidden control elements of the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Yes,** it is valid

**This is Good**

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">
</form>

<form name="form2">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">
</form>
```

**This is also fine** and will generally be interpreted as an array of values, e.g. `{url: [1, 2]}`, depending on what your server does. In a URL encoding, it will look like `url=1&url=2`.

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">
</form>
```

Comment: It is valid. It will create no confusion for the server side language (even PHP, with its conventions for naming fields that share a name, will consistently and predictably handle multiple inputs which don't use that convention). It will create no confusion for JavaScript (which will present the elements as a collection and **not** ignore one of them). It /might/ create confusion for authors who write code without knowing what they are doing, but it is fine by the spec.

Comment: @David Dorward: Thanks for explaining that, I removed that part.

Comment: This post is misleading. inputs with the same name is the same form are part of the HTML standard - they are used, e.g., for checkboxes.

Comment: It is valid to place multiple inputs (hidden or otherwise) with the same name within a single form.  Moreover, it's quite useful when submitting structured lists or associative maps, and is often much cleaner (and less brittle) than hacky DIY serialization.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but a point of clarification. PHP needs you to tell it the elements are forming an array like so: <code> <input type="hidden" name="url[]" value=....... </code> If you don't do this, php will take the last value of the last field and plug it into the form array for the key "url".

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

More, it is essential if you are dealing with radio button groups.

Comment: Exactly. Or with checkboxes, in which case you can put [] at the end "url[]" and it creates an array to be picked up.

Comment: @Kerry — That's a PHPism. Most form handling libraries are quite happy to not have special names for groups of controls.

Answer (score 10):

"This is Not Good" parses correctly on every browser I know of; if two url's appear in the url encoded string, it will be treated as an array. Try this in JQuery:

```
$('<form name="form1">\
     <input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">\
     <input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">\
</form>').serialize()
```

and you will get: `"url=1&url=2"`

a well-written query string parser will return a json structure like this:

```
 {"url":["1", "2"]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes -- each will only submit with their respective forms.

If you have them in the same form, one will override the other and it is not valid.

EDIT:
As pointed out by Mahmoodvcs that the overriding only occurs in some languages (such as PHP) as is not inherent within HTML itself.

Comment: You are wrong. If you have multiple inputs with the same name, one will *not* override the other one. All inputs will be appended to the request's body in the order they appear in html. And it's valid: [HTML form with multiple hidden control elements of the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name)

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs: This is not strictly true.  If the form is posted to a PHP service, then the last value wins.  If you want multiple values assigned to a name, then each name must end in '[]'.

Comment: We are talking about HTML here, not PHP.

Comment: @yardpenalty -- I don't understand your question (unsure if Jeff will respond), but if you're questioning PHP's ability, this is definitely true (at least prior to PHP7 -- I haven't checked if they've changed that yet)

Comment: Sorry I have figured that out. If you are going to process using php you have to make name array. I think it is bootstrap who needs radio buttons to have same name or something. Anyways, yes you can.

Comment: Sorry its jQuery serialize that requires name for form element. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

To test if it is valid or not, creat you page and test at W3C here :

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: And hope that the validator is bugless :-)

Answer (score 2):

A) Your first example is okay, because the forms time of submission will be different:

```
<form id="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">  
</form>
<form id="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">  
</form>
```

B) Your second example is also okay, but not standard coding practice:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="2">  
</form>
```

Java code two extract both values:

```
Map<String,String[]> parmMap = requestObj.getParameterMap();   
String input1 = parmMap.get("url")[0];   
String input2 = parmMap.get("url")[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="url[]" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="url[]" value="2">  
</form>
```

In PHP you will get values with $_POST['url']

```
for($i=0;$i<count(url);$i++)
echo $_POST['url'][$i];
```