# Get array of values from multiple inputs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please let me know how to get values from several input fields?

I have a list with several inputs like this:

```
<li>
<label>Additional Title: </label><input type='text' name='additionaltitlename' ... />
</li>
<li>
<label>Additional Title: </label><input type='text' name='additionaltitlename' ... />
</li>
```

I have a solution in Javascript (on form submit):

```
...
var extratitles = document.getElementsByName('additionaltitlename'); 
var str = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < extratitles.length; i++) { 
      str = str + '|' + extratitles.item(i).value;
    } 
}
```

How do I do the same thing in JQuery?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not valid to have two inputs of the same name. If you want to do this, you can use `<input name="titles[]">`

You can try this:

```
<input name="titles[]">
<input name="titles[]">
​<button>submit</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With this jQuery

```
// click handler
function onClick(event) {
  var titles = $('input[name^=titles]').map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(titles);
  event.preventDefault();
}

// attach button click listener on dom ready
$(function() {
  $('button').click(onClick);
});
```

[See it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7aKG/)

EDIT

This answer gives you the titles in an array instead of a string using a `|` separator.  Personally, I think this is a lot more usable.

If you're just submitting the form and you want to support multiple values, use the `.serialize` method as described in the other answer

Comment: Why not using `this.value`? Is it really necessary to use _jQuery_ for every simple operation?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, [you tell me if it's necessary](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/val.js#L10-L69). The point of the using a lib like jQuery is to a) alleviate concern for a majority of corner cases, and b) provide a consistent, intuitive api. Yes, for INPUT elements, you can use `this.value` pretty reliably, but that changes for things like SELECT. Either way, jQuery doesn't care and gives you an intuitive `.val` method to work in any scenario.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, furthermore, I provided answer that utilizes jQuery and written using jQuery idioms *because* this question was tagged with `jquery`. If this was a vanilla JavaScript question, I would've answered it completely differently.

Comment: Aha, I understood, thanks. I get mixed feeling about this `jQuery` frenzy and I didn't know that even `value` has corner cases.

Comment: "It's not valid to have two inputs of the same name." Perhaps, I'm misunderstanding  but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906793/is-it-valid-to-have-two-input-elements-with-the-same-name) seems to disagree. Also, doesn't using `titles[]` as the name for both inputs contradict the statement that names must be unique.

Answer (score 9):

Use jQuery's native `serialize` function:

```
var data = $('input[name="additionaltitlename"]').serialize();
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

Comment: This doesn't really put the titles in workable form if he wants to do additional processing with javascript

Comment: @macek. he wrote he wants to submit to values with ajax request. `serialize()` is the native solution.

Answer (score 7):

It is very easy in jquery. you can do this as:

```js
types = [];
$("input[name='additionaltitlename']").each(function() {
    types.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(types);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="additionaltitlename1" name="additionaltitlename" class="form-control" value="abc">
<input type="text" id="additionaltitlename2" name="additionaltitlename" class="form-control" value="xyz">
```

Comment: Wow, I'm still getting answers :) Thanks. I now use JS frameworks for things like this.

Comment: thanks, it's worked for me

Comment: I haven´t tohught about that option, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @gdoron's or @macek's answer which are probably the way to go, I'd like to add that all that is wrong with the code you have posted is that you have one `}` too much. This works (although it still has room for improvement):

```
$('#getpreviewbutton').click(function(){

    var extratitles = document.getElementsByName('additionaltitlename'); 
    var str = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < extratitles.length; i++) { 
             str = str + '|' + extratitles.item(i).value;
          }

});​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8XJcc/

I don't know which browser you are using but using sth like Firebug or the Chrome Dev Tools can be pretty handy to spot simple mistakes like this. See **[this reference](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html)** for Chrome or **[this one](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)** for Firefox. Even IE has one - just press F12.

Answer (score 0):

Means:

```
str = '';
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
str = str + '|' + $(this).val();
});
```

or

```
str = '';
$("input[name='additionaltitlename']").each(function() {
str = str + '|' + $(this).val();
});
```

?