# How do I display a jquery variable obtained from user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to be able to click the `submit` button after inputting some text into the forms, then click the `results` button to display what I just input.

It seems like the `titles` variable is "stuck" in the `function onClick(event)` function. How do I "get it out?"

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#submit').click(onClick);
        });

        function onClick(event) {
            var titles = $('input[name^=titles]').map(function(idx, elem) {
                return $(elem).val();
            }).get();
            window.alert(titles); //it displays the titles here
        }

        $("#result").click(function() {
            window.alert('x');
            window.alert(titles); //but not here
            $("p").text(titles[0]);
        });
    });
</script>
    <p>display results here</p>
    <input name="titles[]">
    <input name="titles[]">
    ​<button id="submit">submit</button>
    <button id="results">results</button>
</body>
```

This has probably been answered already but I don't know enough jargon to effectively search for an answer. Also I used some of the code from here cause I want to take in two string inputs: [Get values from multiple inputs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859111/get-values-from-multiple-inputs-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in the selector for your second `click` event. It should be `#results`, rather than `#result`

To the core of the problem, the `titles` variable is out of scope in the second `click` event.

You can remedy this by declaring it outside of either function. This well let you reference it in either one.

```
var titles = [];

function onClick(event) {
  titles = $('input[name^=titles]').map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();
  window.alert(titles);
}

$("#results").click(function() {
  window.alert(titles);
  $("p").text(titles[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Austin when you click on submit jquery calls your function onClick
but this function has nothing to do with the one that you register here

```
$("#result").click(function() { // resultCallback
```

so when you define the variable

```
var titles
```

this variable, like you say, is bound (scoped) to the function onClick and you can't access it from resultCallback. Plus it is completely asynchronous. Clicking on result button (ie calling resultCallback) is not clicking on submit button (ie calling onClick) and because of this the variable titles won't be loaded.

If you want to retrieve the titles create a function getTitles that internally contains

```
return $('input[name^=titles]').map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();
```

and call it from your functions.