# how to decode base64 data into image django - js

Tags: javascript, django, base64, video-capture

im trying to save captured image ( encoding data) into database from canvas , but it only saves a blank image ?

here is my code

```js
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    
    const docs = document.getElementById('document')

    
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
 
    const constraints = {
      video: true,
    };
  
    captureButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const imgFormat = canvas.toDataURL();
      docs.value = imgFormat 
      context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      e.preventDefault();
     
    });
  
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => {
        player.srcObject = stream;
      });
```

```html
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="ltr">{% csrf_token %}

                <input type="text" name="documents" id="document">
                <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
                <button id="capture">Capture</button>
                <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
               

                <button class="header pt-2  text-white px-4 p-1 rounded-lg mt-4">{% trans "save" %}</button>
            </form>
```

and here is my views.py with models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    booking =models.ForeignKey(Booking,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    docs = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_docs)
```

my views.py

```
import base64
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
@login_required
def add_new_image(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Booking,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('documents')
        format, imgstr = data.split(';base64,') 
        ext = format.split('/')[-1] 

        data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name='temp.' + ext)      
        if data:      
            photo = Document.objects.create(
                booking = obj,
                docs = data
            )    
           photo.save()  

        return redirect(reverse_lazy("booking:add_booking",kwargs={"room_no":obj.room_no.room_no}))
    else:
        messages.error(request,_('choose or capture right image ..'))
        
    return render(request,'booking/add_img.html',{'obj':obj,'form':images})
```

i much appreciate your helps , please if you know something about it let me know , thank you so much

Comment: can you check what actually being transferred?

Comment: how to check it ? i think python function works fine , but the problem is the js , but im not good at js

Comment: you can check the devtools. or log the raw request body from python.

Comment: yes , print the value from python function , it shows the encode data , and also in the browser console

Comment: do they match? and what you get when decode manually?

Comment: no , it decodes a blank image

Comment: oh wait. you're not calling toDataURL inside click callback.

Comment: @appleapple i tried it as well , still gives the same output

Comment: can you update the question with toDataUrl inside click handler?

Comment: and what happens when you assign the url to a image element?

Comment: @appleapple i tried it several times , still save a blank image

Comment: Then can you please [edit] the post with it inside?

Comment: @appleapple updated

Comment: you need to draw first then get the result.

Comment: @appleapple you are right , thank you so much

Comment: @appleapple you can write an answer ill accept it , but can we  capture several images ? and save into database ?

Comment: @appleapple sorry , can we make canvas dynamic , for example add new canvas for new capturing image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw first then get the content.

---

For how to do multiple capture.

You can reuse the same canvas, the `toDataURL` is a snapshot of current canvas.

Here is an example.

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player')
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const docs = document.getElementById('document')
const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')


captureButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  // this is just an example, you need a <input> so it's send by form (or use async request)
  let new_image = document.createElement('img')
  new_image.src = canvas.toDataURL()
  form.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',new_image)
});

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then((stream) => { player.srcObject = stream;})
```

```css
form *{max-width:20vw;}
img{display:inline-block;}
canvas{display:none;}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
  <button type="button" id="capture">Capture</button>
  <button>save</button>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/271pvxa3/

Comment: thank you so much , do you familiar with django ? if yes , how to save all of the captured image into the database?

Comment: can i make an input `<input type="file" multiple id="images">` to save the captured  images

Comment: @HunarMohammed I'm not familiar with django. maybe post a new question for that?

Comment: @HunarMohammed you can try [use same name for all images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906814/5980430) or [ajax with FormData (same idea but in ajax form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442)

Comment: sorry , do you have something to add please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404704/how-to-access-to-image-html-tag-from-djangos-view

Comment: because we cant get the img tag from views , i want to add all base64 codes into an input type="text" then i will split them by its data attribute , but it only saves the last picture ? thank you

Comment: @HunarMohammed the `document.createElement('img')` is just for demonstration, you need to create a `<input>` so form send it.

Comment: yes , but i want to sent all encode data to inputs , it only save the last image , i sent all encode data to an input tag then i split the data by `data` from the view (backend-python)

Comment: we cant iterate over all captured images and send them to separate input tags , isnt there any other solution please . i much appreciate your helps ...

Comment: @HunarMohammed what actually not work? why you cannot iterate over all captured images. It seems better to ask new question with updated examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415265/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-an-input-tag-js can you check it out please