# How to append multiple values under one keys using FormData

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, form-data

Given below. I'm trying to find a way how to append the input value under the same keys using FormData

results:

```
sku: [saafasf, hjhkk]
quantity: [3, 3]
```

```
<div>
 <input value="saafasf" readonly="" id="sku" name="sku"> 
 <input value="3" readonly="" id="quantity" name="quantity">
 <input value="hjhkk" readonly="" id="sku" name="sku"> 
 <input value="3" readonly="" id="quantity" name="quantity">
</div>
```

Trying to find a way how to get the array results with multiple values under one key via FromData

Comment: With array of key(?)

Comment: Multiple HTML elements cannot have the same `id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it valid to have two input elements with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906793/is-it-valid-to-have-two-input-elements-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple HTML elements in the same DOM can not contain the same `id`. Hence, you have to convert those into class to get it work.

And then you can access input values under same class using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const skuArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sku"), ({ value }) => value);
const quantityArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".quantity"), ({ value }) => value);

const formDataObj = {
  sku: skuArr,
  quantity: quantityArr
};

console.log(formDataObj);
```

```html
<div>
 <input value="saafasf" readonly="" class="sku" name="sku"> 
 <input value="3" readonly="" class="quantity" name="quantity">
 <input value="hjhkk" readonly="" class="sku" name="sku"> 
 <input value="3" readonly="" class="quantity" name="quantity">
</div>
```