# Getting HTML form values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I get the value of an HTML form to pass to JavaScript?

Is this correct? My script takes two arguments one from textbox, one from the dropdown box.

```
<body>
<form name="valform" action="" method="POST">

Credit Card Validation: <input type="text" id="cctextboxid" name="cctextbox"><br/>
Card Type: <select name="cardtype" id="cardtypeid">
  <option value="visa">Visa</option>
  <option value="mastercard">MasterCard</option>
  <option value="discover">Discover</option>
  <option value="amex">Amex</option>
  <option value="diners">Diners Club</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Verify Credit Card" onclick="isValidCreditCard(document.getElementById('cctextboxid').value,document.getElementById('cardtypeid').value)" />
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value of a form in HTML code" exactly?

Comment: question is quite clear

Comment: @laurentngu the question is does he mean "a value *of* an HTML form", meaning one value out *of* the many values, or does he mean the "*value* of the entire HTML form", meaning all of the values in one big "serialized" value

Comment: The question is clear... but clearly it doesn't make a lot of sense to pass the value of a form.

Comment: Node that while in 2010 the answer here was fairly involved, ever since Object.entries landed in JS, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407161/740553 has been the real answer to the "getting all form values" interpretation of this question.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="value" />
```

JS:

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value;
```

Comment: @shorty876: Did you test it yourself? o_0 That would be a pretty good way of determining whether or not you did it right.

Comment: Yeah, but it just returns a true/false and im not sure how to determine if the function was even called. Thus you can help.

Comment: I tried this out, but `nameValue` is the default value and not what the user entered.

Comment: why name="name", and what if it doesnt have an ID at all?

Comment: @bluejayke there are other javascript methods that get data from HTML tags, such as `getElementsByClassName`. "name" is just a generic attribute placeholder in this case.

Comment: `name="first name"` is the name of the data that was taken from the form and not the id of the html tag. Kind of like in json file `{"first name" : "Mike"}`

Answer (score 164):

If you want to retrieve the form values (such as those that would be sent using an HTTP POST) you can use [FormData class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(form);
  // output as an object
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData));

  // ...or iterate through the name-value pairs
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ": " + pair[1]);
  }
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/Wommgd?editors=1111

---

Alternatively you could use the below less recommended options:

**form-serialize (https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize/)**

```
serialize(document.forms[0]);
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form").serializeArray()
```

Comment: Your first example `FormData` itself doesn't do anything.. you still need to get the values from the form.

Comment: I believe that is incorrect. If when initialising the FormData you specify a form element then it will correctly retrieve the values.

http://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/Wommgd

Comment: The FormData object is not itself the values though. You still need to call and iterate through `FormData.entries()` in order to retrieve the values. Additionally, `FormData.entries()` is not available in Safari, Explorer, or Edge. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Correct in regards to browser compatibility, however there are [polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill).

Regarding iterating through `formData.entries()`, it depends what you are looking for. If you are looking for the value of a single field you could use `formData.get(name)`. Reference: [get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get).

Comment: Yeah I can't get `FormData` to output anything on Chrome.

Comment: To iterate through `.entries()` in ES5 you can do `var entries = formData.entries(); var iter; while(!(iter = entries.next()).done){ console.log(iter.value) }`

Comment: This is the answer I came here for. The question of the post is 'Getting HTML form values'- values being plural. The current top answer only grabs a single input value, I want to know how to grab the entire form and then parse out the values. This should be the top answer.

Comment: IMPORTANT: the inputs need to have the "name" attribute to show up in the FormData entries. Setting an id is not enough.

Answer (score 143):

I think this is the most elegant solution

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const formProps = Object.fromEntries(formData);
}
```

Comment: how is the function called from HTML?

Comment: @Radek Example: `const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");` `loginForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);`

Comment: Worked like a charm , you nailed it! @DedaDev

Comment: This won't work for forms with array fields. Imagine multiple `<input name="categories[]">` this will just capture the last value.

Comment: That is not even a thing in HTML @JonCatmull

Comment: @DedaDev depends what you mean by a "thing" it is valid to have inputs with the same name e.g. for checkboxes and I would expect these to be collected as an array instead of just returning the last field with that name. I think perhaps the example I posted using `[]` is more of an old PHP convention but doesn't really change the point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name

Comment: Note, that in order for this to work, your input field has to have `name="something"` attribute, otherwise it will be result in an empty object

Answer (score 48):

Here is an example from W3Schools:

```
function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
    var obj ={};
    for(var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++){
        var item = elements.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

The demo can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_elements_index).

Comment: Just a warning, if anyone wants to get the selected values of other types of inputs such as radio buttons or checkboxes, this won't do what you want.

Comment: I had to change `var obj = {};` to `var obj = [];`.

Comment: @Sean why would it not work for radio buttons? They appear under the elements property also

Comment: @bluejayke The code will cycle through all of the radio button inputs, and will save the 'value' of the LAST radio button against `obj`, regardless of which one is selected.  The issue is demonstrated here (choose 'Option 1') https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEZXJXBBI7AW

Answer (score 32):

`document.forms` will contain an array of forms on your page. You can loop through these forms to find the specific form you desire.

```
var form = false;
var length = document.forms.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(form.id == "wanted_id") {
        form = document.forms[i];
    }
}
```

Each form has an elements array which you can then loop through to find the data that you want. You should also be able to access them by name

```
var wanted_value = form.someFieldName.value;
jsFunction(wanted_value);
```

Comment: Why the shorter method was not mentioned first? =-D

Comment: @ArturKlesun I would guess it's because at the time a decade ago I started to type the answer, the OP hadn't updated, so I wrote the for loop to handle most situations. I think back then I was also ensuring browser compatibility with IE7 because we didn't have the far better landscape we have today.

Answer (score 27):

This is a developed example of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262933/2464828

Consider

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return check(event)">
    <input name="formula">
</form>
```

Let us assume we want to retrieve the input of name `formula`. This can be done by passing the `event` in the `onsubmit` field. We can then use `FormData` to retrieve the values of this exact form by referencing the `SubmitEvent` object.

```js
const check = (e) => {
    const form = new FormData(e.target);
    const formula = form.get("formula");
    console.log(formula);
    return false
};
```

The JavaScript code above will then print the value of the input to the console.

If you want to iterate the values, i.e., get all the values, then see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Methods

Comment: Great!. This is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

My 5 cents here, using [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) which allows you to query each field by [it's `name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Quick_syntax_example), not only by iteration:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form[name="valform"]');
const ccValidation = form.elements['cctextbox'].value;
const ccType = form.elements['cardtype'].value;
```

Comment: I should note that, the element name is case sensitive. form.elements['cardtype'].value and form.elements['CardType'].value aren't the same.

Answer (score 9):

A one liner for ES6

```js
getFormData = (selector) => Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector(selector)))

console.log('Output of getFormData:')
console.log(getFormData('#myTargetForm'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Get Form Data as Javascript Object</h2>

<form id="myTargetForm">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Define this function in your Javascript:

```
getFormData = (selector) => Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector(selector)))
```

Then just call with any selector e.g.:
`getFormData('#myTargetForm')`

Comment: While this works perfectly with a "standard" select option field, but if multiple is used only the first value is assigned to the array.
Does someone know why and have a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Atrur Klesun's idea... you can just access it by its name if you use getElementById to reach the form. In one line:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').elements['select_name'].value;
```

I used it like so for radio buttons and worked fine. I guess it's the same here.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to change the code as below:

```
<form
   onSubmit={e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

     const elements = Array.from(e.currentTarget);

     const state = elements.reduce((acc, el) => {
       if (el.name) {
         acc[el.name] = el.value;
       }

       return acc;
     }, {});

     console.log(state); // {test: '123'}
   }}
>
   <input name='test' value='123' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer of your question.

You can pass the values of the form fields to the function by using `this.<<name of the field>>.value`.

And also changed input submit to button submit. Called the function from form.

```
<body>
   <form name="valform" method="POST" onsubmit="isValidCreditCard(this.cctextbox.value, this.cardtype.value)">
   Credit Card Validation: <input type="text" id="cctextboxid" name="cctextbox"><br/>
   Card Type: 
   <select name="cardtype" id="cardtypeid">
      ...
   </select>
   <br/>
   <button type="submit">Verify Credit Card</button>
</body>
```

Technically you can do it in your function by using `document.getElementById("cctextboxid")`. But his solution is concise and simple code.

Comment: Very clean solution!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but maybe someone down the line can use this.

```js
// use document.form["form-name"] to reference the form
const ccForm = document.forms["ccform"];

// bind the onsubmit property to a function to do some logic
ccForm.onsubmit = function(e) {

  // access the desired input through the var we setup
  let ccSelection = ccForm.ccselect.value;
  console.log(ccSelection);

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form name="ccform">
  <select name="ccselect">
    <option value="card1">Card 1</option>
    <option value="card2">Card 2</option>
    <option value="card3">Card 3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<form id='form'>
    <input type='text' name='title'>
    <input type='text' name='text'>
    <input type='email' name='email'>
</form>
```

```js
const element = document.getElementByID('#form')
const data = new FormData(element)
const form = Array.from(data.entries())
/*
form = [
    ["title", "a"]
    ["text", "b"]
    ["email", "c"]
]
*/
for (const [name, value] of form) {
    console.log({ name, value })
    /*
    {name: "title", value: "a"}
    {name: "text", value: "b"}
    {name: "email", value: "c"}
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several easy-to-use form serializers with good documentation.

In order of Github stars,

1. [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)
2. [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object)
3. [form2js](https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js)
4. [form-serialize](https://github.com/defunctzombie/form-serialize)

Comment: do ya really need a whole array just for that?

Answer (score 2):

Some answers above didn't cater for forms with multiple fields with the same name e.g.multiple `<input name="categories[]">` so I made this quickly. It expects field with the same name that you want to collect as an array to end in `[]` as a convention but could be updated to handle other scenarios.

```
function getFormValues(form) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  return Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((prev, [inputName, val]) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      [inputName]: inputName.endsWith('[]')
        ? prev[inputName]
          ? [...prev[inputName], val]
          : [val]
        : val,
    };
  }, {});
}

// alternative if you don't like reducers and nested ternary statements
function getFormValues(form) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const values = {};
  for (const [inputName, val] of formData.entries()) {
    if (inputName.endsWith('[]')) {
      values[inputName] = values[inputName] ? [...values[inputName], val] : [val];
    } else {
      values[inputName] = val;
    }
  }
  return values;
}

// then attach this to form submit 
function onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const values = getFormValues(e.target);
   // etc...
}
```

values gives something like `{ "single": "something", "categories[]": ["one", "two"] }`

Comment: This is by far the best answer I've seen so far. Thanks!

Comment: Best (and correct) answer for single and as well multiple input values.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with one for-of loop you can get all field values even checkboxes values also.

In your HTML you should bind a `handlSubmit()` on your forms `onsubmit` event

```html
<form name="contact_form" 
      id="contact-form" 
      class="form-controller" 
      onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)"
>
```

in your javascript your code should apply the following logic no matter what name your assigned to your fields.

```js
const handleSubmit = (event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    formObj = {};
    
    for (const [fieldName] of formData) {
        const fieldValue = formData.getAll(fieldName);
        formObj[fieldName] = fieldValue.length == 1 ? fieldValue.toString() : fieldValue
    }
    console.log('formObj',formObj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution to serialize a form without any libraries

```js
function serializeIt(form) {
  return (
    Array.apply(0, form.elements).map(x => 
      (
        (obj => 
          (
            x.type == "radio" ||
            x.type == "checkbox"
          ) ?
            x.checked ? 
              obj
            : 
              null
          :
            obj
        )(
          {
            [x.name]:x.value
          }
        )
      )
    ).filter(x => x)
  );
}

function whenSubmitted(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(
      serializeIt(document.forms[0]),
      4, 4, 4
    )
  )
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="whenSubmitted(event)">
<input type=text name=hiThere value=nothing>
<input type=radio name=okRadioHere value=nothin>
<input type=radio name=okRadioHere1 value=nothinElse>
<input type=radio name=okRadioHere2 value=nothinStill>

<input type=checkbox name=justAcheckBox value=checkin>
<input type=checkbox name=justAcheckBox1 value=checkin1>
<input type=checkbox name=justAcheckBox2 value=checkin2>

<select name=selectingSomething>
<option value="hiThere">Hi</option>
<option value="hiThere1">Hi1</option>
<option value="hiThere2">Hi2</option>
<option value="hiThere3">Hi3</option>
</select>
<input type=submit value="click me!" name=subd>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var inputs = document.getElementById("form_id_here").elements;
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].type === "text" || inputs[i].type === "textarea") {
        console.log(inputs[i].value); // Get value of input tag which you have entered.
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="note_text" />

let value = document.getElementById("note_text").value;
```