# web.input() not taking on form data

Tags: javascript, python, forms, input, web.py

So I'm trying to create a simple registration form for users to enter their info, and submit for processing. I'm having trouble with grabbing the form data. The way the site is setup, I've got the "/register" form that then sends an ajax request to the url "/postregister". From there, enters the class that gets the data from web.input(), and then references the data for whatever I need to. Or at least that's the intention...

The problem that I have lies in the very first step: Grabbing the form data from "/register" page. Nothing is actually passed along.

Here is the register.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Register Account</h2>
    <br /><br />
    <form id="register-form">
        <div class="form-group label-static is-empty>
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username..."/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The main controller.py:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
)

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home()

class Register:
    def GET(self):
        return self.Register()

class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        print "data:   " + str(data) # This line is for debugging
        return data.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

plus the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("loaded");

    $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $("#register-form").serialize();
        console.log(form); //This is just for debugging
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postregistration',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

When I run the controller.py, and navigate to localhost:8080/register, I'm prompted with the form to fill out. *Success!* Now I enter the information and click submit. **Problem!!** When checking the console log, the form is not actually being captured. An "AttributeError" is raised, with AttributeError: 'username'. And sure enough, the controller.py prints:

```
data:   <storage {}>
```

So I see that web.input() grabs no data. Going back a little further, in the web console, I can see that "loaded" is written, then when I click submit, I can see that something (but actually nothing) is written to the console. Again, all signs point to me not grabbing the form data. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the serialize method is omitting all of the fields because they dont include a name attribute. if you add it to the register entries like this:

```
<div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a username" />
</div>
```

then the form variable will populate. this still returns a 500 error when trying to access a field with the line data.username....

sources:
[JavaScript - Getting HTML form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values)
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. This did the trick. I guess next time I'll look harder for the answer to my question. Thanks!!

Comment: were you able to fix the 500 error from the data.username line? im still stuck on that

Comment: yes. By adding the name="username" attribute in the HTML file it worked perfectly. I can now take the user input and send it to my MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I think your jQuery selector here is wrong:

`var form = $("register-form").serialize();`

Ought to be

```
var form = $("#register-form").serialize();
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

This would possibly result in no element being selected for .serialize() to serialize.

Comment: The change had no effect. I see from your Source where I went wrong, but it did not fix things.

Comment: I'm less of an expert on Python, however could your issue arise from the indentation of "return data.username" in class PostRegistration? From what I know of Python it looks like you're calling the return outside of the POST(self) function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The indentation of "return data.username is actually correct. It may look strange due to the print statement above, but I believe that the issue is somewhere wayyyy before the final return statement in the main python controller.

Comment: I apologize. I did not quite see the error that you pointed out. You are correct about the indentation error. Aside from that, it still does not work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error:

```
class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
    print "data:   " + str(data) # This line is for debugging
    return data.username
```

Needs to be:

```
class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
       data = web.input()
       print "data:   " + str(data) # This line is for debugging
       return data.username
```

On the jquery side, `.serialize()` will ignore all inputs which do not have a `name` attribute. That's why you're not getting anything sent across the wire.

Solution is add `name='username'` to your input.

Comment: You are correct. Rather than copy and paste the code, I typed it so that I could review each line individually. The correction you've made to my syntax does not change the fact that data still captures no information from the form.