# Angular 2 get element by dynamic id

Tags: angular, patch

How can I get/update value of element with dynamic id?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{'lat' + ind}}" formControlName="lat">
```

I can't use `ngAfterViewInit() {}` because I need to update dynamic input after server responce

```
this.someService.getData().subscribe(
                  (response) => {this.data = response.json()
                                 this.lon = this.data.x;
                                 this.lat = this.data.y;
                                 this.ind = this.data.ind;
                                // UPDATE MY 'lat+ind' and 'lon+ind' HERE
                  },
                  (error) => console.log('ERROR: ' + error)
          );
```

Comment: You could use `document.querySelector('#lat' + this.ind)` to retrieve the DOM element

Comment: And how to get value and update?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution for Angular, but you could use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Here's an example:

```
const input = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('#lat' + this.ind);

input.value = 'value'; // set value
```

**Edit**

Please read https://angular.io/guide/forms to understand how forms work with Angular.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem that inputs got new values, but form.data object no: "addresses": [ { "lat": 0, "lon": 0 }, { "lat": 0, "lon": 0 } ]

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin As far as I can see you're not setting any input value. You're setting the **id**. See my edit.

Comment: Your answer works. New value appeared in inputs, but didn't appear in form.value object. That is a problem

Comment: Forms don't have an attribute called `value`, only inputs do (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.someService.getData().subscribe(
    (response) => {
                     this.ngZone.run(function() {
                       this.data = response.json()
                       this.lon = this.data.x;
                       this.lat = this.data.y;
                       this.ind = this.data.ind;
                     };)
                  },
(error) => console.log('ERROR: ' + error)
);
```

Note: you have to import NgZone and inject it at your constructor.

You need to do this because your view is not updated after you receive your response from your service. My code above will revive your view and publish updated values to your ID.

Your template gets published in the beginning when your lat and ind are still undefined. Then when you make your service call and you get a response, you must tell angular to update your view with the new values.

Note: You can also use ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() to do this

Comment: I think he wants to retrieve the input element - which has a dynamic ID.

Comment: He doesn't need to retrieve the input element. Angular will update the input element with the new lat and ind values automatically

Comment: Oh, I probably misinterpreted the question, my bad. Though I don't think `.run()` will change anything as it is used to **reenter** the Angular zone, but I don't see any usage of `.runOutsideAngular()`.

Comment: "Zones wrap asynchronous browser APIs, and notify a consumer when an asynchronous task has started or ended. Angular takes advantage of these APIs to get notified when any asynchronous task is done. This includes things like XHR calls, setTimeout() and pretty much all user events like click, submit, mousedown, … etc.

Once notified, Angular knows that it has to perform change detection because any of the asynchronous operations might have changed the application state. This, for instance, is always the case when we use Angular’s Http service to fetch data from a remote server."

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html

Comment: Yes, my problem that inputs got new values, but form.data object no: "addresses": [
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lon": 0
    },
  {
      "lat": 0,
      "lon": 0
    }
  ]

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you are trying to say @Serhiog.Lazin

Comment: @VinodBhavnani From the same article: "The nice thing about this is that we as developers don’t have to care about notifying Angular to perform change detection, because Zones will do it for us as Angular subscribes to them under the hood.".

Comment: After server callback I am updating value of dynamic inputs. It works, but these values don't appear in form.value object. They appear only if I am typing on input manualy. My updating of inputs don't makes changes in form.value object