# Javascript, form values

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

I have some variables in Javascript if statement which capture the values in a form. A check box and a couple of drop downs. Is there any way I can make the variables a bit dynamic? For example, if the user decides to select a different option then the value updates? At the moment it only captures what is currently selected on page load.

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("page") >= 0 && document.cookie.search('myCookie') < 0){ 


var productvalue = document.querySelector('input[name=product]:checked').value;

var amount = document.getElementById("frm-amount");
var amountValue = amount.options[amount.selectedIndex].value;

var term = document.getElementById("frm-term");
var termValue = term.options[term.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Getting HTML form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the **[event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

For the *select box*, you need to add the `change` event listeners and for the input fields, you could go with `keyup` (or again, `change`).

Also, you need to provide a bit more of your HTML code for a more refined solution.

But, I hope that gives a brief idea.