# Can we loop through event.target and get attribute values for each element inside a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if we can loop through event.target and get attribute values for each element inside a form.
I am trying to implement this in Reactjs. There is just a basic form as given below

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

and in the handleSubmit function, the code is as given below

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let target   = event.target;
    let formData = {};

    formData.username = target.name.value;
    formData.email    = target.email.value;
    formData.passowrd = target.passowrd.value;

    console.log(formData);
}
```

I get the user filled data in the console.log as required. But as you can see I need specify each and every element to get the formData, Imagine a form with 20-30 elements.

I tried to do something as given below

```
count = 0;
formData = [];
foreach(target as item) {
    formData[count][item.name] = item.value;
}
```

It's basically PHP code But put here so that you can see what am trying to do.
I tried to do this js and it gives me all kind of errors. Please let know if it's possible in js
If so? How can I achieve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values

Comment: It's imposible to  do it  like you tried. I think you have to implement  an  abstraction where   you will register each field to  have access   to  them as you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think u r looking for this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let target   = event.target;
    let formData = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        formData[target.elements[i].getAttribute("name")] = target.elements[i].value;
    }
    console.log('formData', formData); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. You cache all the inputs and then loop over them with `forEach` when the form is submitted.

```js
// Cache the form element, and the inputs
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');

// Attach an event listener to the form that calls
// handleSubmit when it is submitted
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit, false);

function handleSubmit(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Create a form object
  const form = {};

  // Iterate over your inputs and set the input name as your
  // property key, and the value as its value
  inputs.forEach(({ name, value }) => form[name] = value);
  console.log(form);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.from()` to instansiate a new array from a form.

For example:

```
const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const inputs = Array.from(event.target);

  inputs.forEach(input => {
    console.log(input.name, input.value);
  });
}
```