# Saving value from HTML form to use in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having some issues whilst trying to save a user's input for a d3 calculation. I've looked at few threads, including [JavaScript - Getting HTML form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values) but the suggested solutions don't seem to work in the case below for some reason.

Here's my HTML:

```
   <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="lead">
                What is your annual household income?
            </p>
            <input id="userAnnualIncome form-control-sm" type="number" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's what I had in JS:

```
let annualIncome = document.getElementById('userAnnualIncome').value
```

When I console.log(annualIncome) - I get the following error:

```
app.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:95)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (d3.v7.min.js:2)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your ID is `userAnnualIncome form-control-sm` so you try to select something that doesnt exist. If you put the bootstrap part in the class attribute and only the `userAnnualIncome` as ID it works just fine

```js
let val = document.getElementById('userAnnualIncome').value

console.log(val)
```

```html
<input id="userAnnualIncome" class="form-control-sm" type="number" value="12123">
```