# How to set up filter options for search results in semantic html

Tags: html, wai-aria

does anyone have experience setting up  semantically meaningful filter option alongside search results?
I mean something like:

```
<ol>
<li>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="filter-by-name" value="pete"> Pete</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="filter-by-name" value="Jakov">Jakov</label>
</li>
```

or should I do something more along the lines of:

```
<ol role="filter">
<li>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="filter-by-name" value="pete"> Pete</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

As they are form controls, to be semantic they would need to use the correct markup.

Based on the **Grouping Controls** section on [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/grouping/#checkboxes)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>I want to receive</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="check_1">
        <label for="check_1">The weekly newsletter</label>
    </div>
    […]
</fieldset>
```

Your example should be:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Filter by:</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="pete">
        <label for="pete">Pete</label>
    </div>
    […]
</fieldset>
```

In regards to the `name` attribute this is your preference, from an answer on [What is the purpose of the `name` attribute in a checkbox input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626923/3337722)

> Dont be confused because of name="checkbox". It could more logically
>   be name="drink" and type=checkbox.
>
> In the above case, you have multiple checkboxes with the same name.
>   When several checkboxes have the same name, the form will send a group
>   of values to the server in the request. Note: only the values of the
>   checked checkboxes will be sent to the server.
>
> Ideally these are used to allow multiple choice questions where more
>   than one answer is allowed. As opposed to radio buttons, where only
>   one answer is allowed among the options.