# Do browsers preserve order of inputs with same name on GET/POST?

Tags: html, cross-browser, wsgi

I have this HTML code with multiple `input`s with the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" value="42" name="authors" />
<input type="hidden" value="13" name="authors" />
<input type="hidden" value="33" name="authors" />
```

The order of the values is important. Does the HTML spec define that user agents have to preserve this order, and if yes, do the common (market share > 1%) browsers follow this definition?

Bonus points if someone knows if WSGI and especially Django preserve the order server-side :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, they should be sent in the order they appear according to the [html rfc](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt)

See 8.2.1. The form-urlencoded Media Type:

> The fields are listed in the order they appear in the document with the
>   name separated from the value by `=`
>   and the pairs separated from each
>   other by `&`. Fields with null values
>   may be omitted. In particular,
>   unselected radio buttons and
>   checkboxes should not appear in the
>   encoded data, but hidden fields with
>   VALUE attributes present should.

I've found in the spec for [html 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) too:

For url encoded data:

> The control names/values are listed in
>   the order they appear in the document.
>   The name is separated from the value
>   by `=` and name/value pairs are
>   separated from each other by `&`.

For multipart data (thanks @Chuck):

> A "multipart/form-data" message
>   contains a series of parts, each
>   representing a successful control. The
>   parts are sent to the processing agent
>   in the same order the corresponding
>   controls appear in the document
>   stream. Part boundaries should not
>   occur in any of the data; how this is
>   done lies outside the scope of this
>   specification.

Comment: The same ordering guarantee is also given for multipart-type forms.

Comment: I'm still trying to find information about html 4.0, that rfc was for html 2.0. But I don't think they break compability, however.. Still searching

Comment: I've found it. Updating answer

Answer (score 6):

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `text/plain` lays out an algorithm that *"For each entry in the form data set [...] Append"*, resulting in the same order.

As for `multipart/form-data`: *"The order of parts must be the same as the order of fields in the form data set. Multiple entries with the same name must be treated as distinct fields."*

This would not be complete without obtaining order of the form data set as derived from the document: the same spec defines an algorithm for [constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set) that *"Loop: For each element field in controls, in tree order, run the following substeps* and only skip or *Append an entry*.

Therefore for HTML5-compliant user agents, whatever the encoding, **the non-skipped parameters are tree-ordered, with duplicates allowed**.