# multiple submit button

Tags: php, javascript

i've a form POST with multiple submit buttons. i understand to get this to work i must have them with different name.

however, i wanna keep the name to be the same because i wanna handle the POST using a single script.

im not sure if there is other way but i know javascript can be used. however, how do i get the value of the hidden value associated to the button since now they have only a single ??

my example is as follows:

```
<form method="Post" action="file.php">

<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="1" />
<input type="submit" id="btnremove" name="btnremove" value="Remove" inputbutton/>

<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="2" />
<input type="submit" id="btnremove" name="btnremove" value="Remove" inputbutton/>

<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="2" />
<input type="submit" id="btnremove" name="btnremove" value="Remove" inputbutton/>

</form>
```

Comment: You can't use the same "id" value for multiple elements.

Comment: hi, i've seen web pages using javascript which accept removeid as parameters. i would like to know how to create a javascript which accept the value and post it to php??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hidden values are not associated with the buttons at all.  Furthermore, you cannot use the same value for the ID attribute on multiple elements.

What I usually do in this situation is check the POST vars.  Name them something like `remove_1`, `remove_2`, etc.  Then you can search through your POST vars, find all of them beginning with `remove_` (or whatever format you choose... don't use it for other things) and then you can parse out the ID of what you are trying to remove.

Comment: hi i have decided to go with this idea. i think its the most feasible and easiest =).

Comment: hey Brad, how do i check the POST vars??

Comment: **$remove_vars = preg_grep('/^remove_.*/', $_POST);** That will give you an array of all the form elements you submitted that start with "remove_".

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use 3 different forms, all with the same action. No JavaScript needed.

```
<form method="Post" action="file.php">
<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Remove" inputbutton/>
</form>

<form method="Post" action="file.php">
<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="2" />
<input type="submit" value="Remove" inputbutton/>
</form>

<form method="Post" action="file.php">
<input type="hidden" name="removeid" value="2" />
<input type="submit" value="Remove" inputbutton/>
</form>
```

Comment: hi, i actually used that but these multiple form actually resides in a main form

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but HTML doesn't support nesting <form> tags.

Comment: but it does support multiple form elements with same name inside the same form, so why having 3 different forms?

Comment: If you were to submit the same form with three <input type="hidden"> tags sharing the same name but different values, I don't know how PHP would interpret this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using two different methods:

1. If you absolutely have to show 3 different buttons, use a separate *<form>* wrapper for each one. Put each "removeid" element in a different form.
2. Otherwise, just have a single button, and when submitted, use JavaScript to set the value of a single hidden input element before posting the form. You can find sample code for this easily with a Google query for "javascript+form+post".

Answer (score 0):

You **can** have one form with more than one submit button sharing the same name, your initial assumption was wrong.

The following code is perfectly valid, and the *value* of the clicked submit button will be passed along with its name:

```
<form action="TestZone.html" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="MySubmit" value="First" /><input type="submit" name="MySubmit" value="Second" /><input type="submit" name="MySubmit" value="Third" />
</form>
```

You can't have multiple elements with same ID, but same name for form elements is common and valid.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have resolved my questions by following Brad solution. to get the POST var, i did this:

```
//Check if Remove btn is clicked
  $isClickRemove = false;
  $cid = "";
  foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
    $pos = strpos($k,"btnremovecart_");

    if($pos !== false){
      $pos2 = strpos($k,"_"); //2nd pos to get cartID
      $cid = substr($k,$pos2+1);
      $isClickRemove = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

my html looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnremovecart_11" name="btnremovecart_11" value="Remove" />
```

hope this helps =)

Answer (score -1):

You can't because there is no way of distingushing the different fields.

Comment: There is a way, using their value.

Comment: which currently is all the same.