# How to post json ajax?

Tags: jquery

I would like to send an array encoded in JSON using ajax, but my code bellow is producing some errors.

HTML

```
 <table width="200" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>
          <input name="table[]" type="text" id="table[]" value="5" />
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>menu</td>
        <td><input name="menu[]" type="text" id="menu[]" value="noodle" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>number</td>
        <td><input name="number[]" type="text" id="number[]" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>note</td>
        <td><input name="note[]" type="text" id="note[]" value="no " /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td><input name="table[]" type="text" id="table[]" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>menu</td>
        <td><input name="menu[]" type="text" id="menu[]" value="beer" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>number</td>
        <td><input name="number[]" type="text" id="number[]" value="2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>note</td>
        <td><input name="note[]" type="text" id="note[]" value="-" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<button id="save-menu">save</button>
<button id="calculator">calculator</button>
```

jQuery : If I click the button `save-menu` it sends some data to menu/order. Also when I click the button `calculator` it sends some data to the calculator page. The problem is when I try to send the data using jQuery it does not send all of the data in the array.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save-menu').click(function() {

            $.post('menu/order', {      
                table : $('select#workplace-table').val(),
                'mid[]' : $('input#order-mid').val(),
                'number[]' : $('input#order-number').val(),
                'note[]' : $('input#order-note').val(),
                }); 


       $('#calculator').click(function() {

            $.post('menu/calculator, {      
                table : $('select#workplace-table').val(),
                'mid[]' : $('input#order-mid').val(),
                'number[]' : $('input#order-number').val(),
                }); 


            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hammerhito/vsy5J/) with what I think you want.

Your selector $('input#order-number') is looking for a single input

```
<input id="order-number">
```

In your HTML you should not use the same id multiple times and while it's valid to use the same name for all the inputs and JQuery will select it correctly, some libraries may not. (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name).)  I would recommend using a class name to handle the selection like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="1" />
  <input type="text" class="number" value="2" />
  <input type="text" class="number" value="3" />
  <input type="text" class="number" value="4" />
  <input type="text" class="number" value="5" />
</form>
```

In your JS

```
'number[]' : $('input#order-number').val()
```

will add a property names 'number[]' to your JSON object, however I suspect you really want that to be an array like this:

```
"numbers" : [ 1, 2 ]
```

Also, the JSON standard requires double quotes.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote).

In the JS you will need to get all the  elements and add their values to an array.

```
var numbers = [];  
$('.number').each(function(idx,el){ 
    numbers.push( $(el).val() );
});

var jsonObj = {
    "numbers" : numbers
};
```

Updating your code to use classes for selection and creating the arrays like above should give you the correct JSON object you want to POST.